# How to ensure RemoteViewsService is run in the background in Oreo?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

Android 8 has its [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html), so when we started targeting Oreo we changed our services to using [`JobIntentSerivce`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) to be able to get work done.

**However, we have a widget that updates every few minutes with live score data. The widget's service extends the good old [`RemoteViewsService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.html). How can we make sure that the widget is updated even when the app is in the background?**

I've taken a look at the [suggestions in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46179256/467650), but they all seem to have some caveats:

- `JobScheduler` needs a `JobIntentSerivce` which I can't see how can be combined with `RemoteViewsService` (**or can it somehow?**)
- [`PendingIntent.getForegroundService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getForegroundService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) is not perfect when on a poor Internet connection (or maybe a slow device) and will sometimes either give an ANR, and we ideally don't really want to show a notification when we see the time limit is closing in on us

I haven't experimented with [`BroadcastReceiver.goAsync()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync()) yet, but maybe that is my best shot?

Comment: the first link you posted says: `"Bound services are not affected"`, and i believe `RemoteViewsService` is such a service

Comment: @pskink That's interesting. It does indeed look like a bound service. But, we get a few complaints about the widget not updating and I personally saw the same and got these in my log: `W/ActivityManager: Background start not allowed: service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.app.WidgetService (has extras) } to com.example.appWidgetService from pid=-1 uid=10447 pkg=com.example.app`

Comment: `com.example.app.WidgetService` and `com.example.appWidgetService` are different, is there some typo?

Comment: Yes, that's my bad. I searched and replaced the actual package + class name. I always do that on SO. Sorry. :)

Comment: Any news? I have the same problem :(

Comment: @Kram Unfortunately not. We will probably just stop using RemoteViewsService.

Comment: @RoySolberg ok. In addition I have a problem that the buttons don't react when I click on them. It looks like the AppWidgetProvider was killed. Are you familiar with this?

Comment: @Kram No, we haven't seen that. Not even on the Huawei phones that really have messed up the widgets.

Comment: Did you solve this?  If you moved away from RemoveViewsService, what direction did you take?

Comment: @KeithEntzeroth Can't say I really solved it. We had to keep using `RemoteViewsService` to have a dynamic list of items. For Android 8 and 9 we have to use a lot of hacks to have the service running somewhat reliable, but there are so many bugs it's a mess now. Especially https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072 are haunting us.