# How to properly update a collection in a widget UI on Android 8.0 (API level 26+)?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-8.0-oreo, remoteview

**The story so far:**

I have two Android Home Screen widgets to mainain and I recently updated the host App to support Android 8.0 (targetSdkVersion 26). Obviously, the long-running services, which were used to update the widgets, got killed by the Android system at some point, so as an interim fix, I flagged the services as ForegroundService, showing a corresponding notification to the user. I'm currently looking for a way to optimize this, however, and find a solution that is less visible to the user.

One of the widgets I already fixed. It does not use any collections as part of its view, therefore it does not rely on RemoteViewsService/RemoteView. I was able to fix the update process with the help of a JobIntentService (and AlarmManager, which the widgets had already been using anyway).

**The problem:**

I'm having a hard time, however, to fix the other widget, which uses a collection (ListView) in its UI. I tried to bypass the usage of RemoteViewsService/RemoteView and add my RemoteViews directly, similar to how I do it in the other widget. But then I simply get loading errors and the widget shows some fallback UI.

The official widget documentation also still describes RemoteViewsService/RemoteViewsFactory as mandatory when working with collections in widgets: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/

This other StackOverflow question ends with the questioner suggesting to stop using RemoteViewsService, but the discussion says nothing about how to continue to support collections:
[How to ensure RemoteViewsService is run in the background in Oreo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184186/how-to-ensure-remoteviewsservice-is-run-in-the-background-in-oreo)

I find it a bit weird that there would be a way to avoid foreground notifications for one widget but to have to rely on them for another, depending on the structure of the widget's UI. I would expect Google to provide something like a RemoteViewsJobIntentService, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that.

**My question:**

- Is it the officially best practice to update a collection (e.g.
  ListView) in an Android widget on Android 8.0 / targetSdkVersion
  26 to use RemoteViewsService and flagging it as a foreground service?
- If not, how else can a collection (e.g. ListView) in an Android
  widget on Android 8.0 / targetSdkVersion 26 be updated?

Comment: **Update:** I fixed my problem by stripping the RemoteViewsService of all excess responsibilites, which it previously had and introducing a separate JobIntentService for these responsibilities. So, in effect, the widget is operated by two services now: a JobIntentService, as well as a RemoteViewsService, which does nothing else than to update the views. This runs fine on Android 8+ now. Maybe this helps people who have their RemoteViewsService cluttered with additional stuff. Just clean the class up and separate concerns.