# Android service background Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-appwidget, android-8.1-oreo

in my Android project i've created an custom clock widget with a service which contains an instance of Broadcast Reciever and an intent filter. The Broadcast Reciever provides the update of the widget every time arrives the ACTION_TIME_TICK. This is working perfectly when set targetSdkVersion to 25, in gradle. But if i target to sdk 27, the service stops after few minutes. I've read the documentation about background executions limit in Android O, but i can't find any approach that is useful for my project. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried calling `startForeground` in your service?

Comment: The best way to schedule repeating tasks on api 21+ is using a JobScheduler. You should give it a try, read here: https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129. Below api 21 the AlramManager will do the job.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes i tried, but this approach needs a persistent notification

Comment: To clear things up: your service stops while the device screen is still on, or does your app needs to be constantly updated even in background?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I need a service that costantly updates the widget in background, even if the mainactivity is destroyed

Comment: @deno750, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181049/7470253) will be a good start for you. I personally think that if screen is off, no updates are necessary (it will be enough if widget will play catch-up once the screen is on again).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can try which, when used in concert, should be able to cut through all of the idle/standby/doze modes (irrespective of OS version).

1. Use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead of an ordinary `BroadcastReceiver`. Make sure you include the `WAKE_LOCK` permission to use it correctly.
2. Use the `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` method (on API 23 & above) to schedule the Intent for the receiver:

   ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
           setExact(...);
       }
       else {
           set(...);
       }
   }
   else {
       setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look for your solution.